# Overloading extraction operator with optional empty values?

Tags: c++, c++14

I wish to fill my very simple struct with data:

```
struct base {
    int a;
    std::string s1;
    std::string s2;
    int b;
}
```

To do this, I am implementing the extraction operator (and also the insertion one for debug):

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const base& b) {
    os << "a = " << b.a << "\n" << "s1='" << b.s1 << "'\n" << "s2='" << b.s2 << "'\n" << "b = " << b.b;
    return os;
}

friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, base& b) {
    std::cout << "is.good: " << is.good() << ", is.eof: " << is.eof() << ", in_avail:" << is.rdbuf()->in_avail() << std::endl;
    is >> b.a;

    std::cout << "is.good: " << is.good() << ", is.eof: " << is.eof() << ", in_avail:" << is.rdbuf()->in_avail() << std::endl;
    is >> b.s1;

    std::cout << "is.good: " << is.good() << ", is.eof: " << is.eof() << ", in_avail:" << is.rdbuf()->in_avail() << std::endl;
    is >> b.s2;

    std::cout << "is.good: " << is.good() << ", is.eof: " << is.eof() << ", in_avail:" << is.rdbuf()->in_avail() << std::endl;
    is >> b.b;
    return is;
}
```

I have created two simple test cases: first with each field correctly filled, and second with missing value:

```
std::string basevalue1("1\nhello\nworld\n2");
std::cout << "Parsing basevalue1: " << std::endl << basevalue1 << std::endl << std::endl;

base b1;
std::stringstream buffer1(basevalue1);
buffer1 >> b1;

std::cout << "Parsed b1: " << std::endl << b1 << std::endl << std::endl;
```

This first case works perfectly:

```
Parsing basevalue1: 
1
hello
world
2

is.good: 1, is.eof: 0, in_avail:15
is.good: 1, is.eof: 0, in_avail:14
is.good: 1, is.eof: 0, in_avail:8
is.good: 1, is.eof: 0, in_avail:2
Parsed b1: 
a = 1
s1='hello'
s2='world'
b = 2
```

Now to the second one:

```
std::string basevalue2("1\nhello\n\n2");
std::cout << "Parsing basevalue2: " << std::endl << basevalue2 << std::endl << std::endl;

base b2;
std::stringstream buffer2(basevalue2);
buffer2 >> b2;

std::cout << "Parsed b2: " << std::endl << b2;
Parsed b1: 
a = 1
s1='hello'
s2='world'
b = 2
```

As you can see, there are 2 `\n`s after *hello*. I wish to keep `s2` empty, however extraction operator just skips the empty *field* and fills s2 with data, leaving garbage in b:

```
Parsing basevalue2: 
1
hello

2

is.good: 1, is.eof: 0, in_avail:10
is.good: 1, is.eof: 0, in_avail:9
is.good: 1, is.eof: 0, in_avail:3
is.good: 0, is.eof: 1, in_avail:0
Parsed b2: 
a = 1
s1='hello'
s2='2'
b = 717214096
```

I need "2" go into "b", and s2 shall stay empty.

Full example is priveded here: https://godbolt.org/z/YbaqMvbjf

I have also tried to change the `\n` to some more generic character to see if that makes any difference, but unfortunately is not:

```
struct separation: std::ctype<char> {
    separation(char separator): std::ctype<char>(get_table(separator)) {}

    static std::ctype_base::mask const* get_table(char separator) {
        static std::vector<std::ctype_base::mask> rc(table_size, std::ctype_base::mask());
        rc[separator] = std::ctype_base::space;
        return &rc[0];
    }
};

buffer2.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new separation(';')));
```

How am I supposed to move on an empty field, during extraction?

Latest available compiler I can use is C++14.

Comment: If you want to read line by line then use `std::getline` not `>>`.

Comment: You should not use `std::cout <<` inside the overloaded `operator>>`.

Comment: Are you looking for [std::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)?

Comment: @john: I don't want to read line by line, this is just for illustration. I wish to read each field separated by `;` as shown at the end.

Comment: @JasonLiam: yes, I know. it's for illustration to show nothing is indicating the empty field.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: I forgot to add I need to solve this with C++14, and *optional* was not yet supported back then.

Comment: `operator >>` skips space (for most types), so `\n\n2` is not empty followed by 2, but just 2. (2 is a valid input for `std::string`).